# Как преобразовать текстовую переменную String в int?

Tags: java, строки, кодировка, char, int

Как преобразовать текстовую переменную `String`, с фиксированной длиной 16 символов, в `int` и обратно?

Мне не нужно простое преобразование типов переменных, мне нужно преобразование строки в кодировке ASCII в цифровое представление этой строки.

Например, строка `AsDfGhJkLoIpUyTr` будет конвертирована в `065115068102071104074107076111073112085121084114`.

Comment: Посмотрите на методы `chars()` и `codePoints()` класса [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Преобразовать такое число в int не получится, так как int имеет размер 32 бита и может иметь максимальное значение 2147483647. Можете преобразовать в строку с байтами, или в массив интов, в зависимости от того, для чего вам это нужно:

```java
String s = "AsDfGhJkLoIpUyTr";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
s.chars().forEach(sb::append);  // Получите строку 
System.out.println(sb.toString());

sb.setLength(0);
s.chars().forEach(i -> { // Получите строку с ведущими нулями
    if (i < 10) {
        sb.append("00");
    }
    if (i < 100) {
        sb.append("0");
    }
    sb.append(i);
});
System.out.println(sb.toString());

List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
s.chars().forEach(ints::add); // Получите массив байт в виде int'ов
ints.stream().forEach(System.out::print);

// Получить массив байт и воссоздать из него строку
byte[] byteArr = new byte[ints.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.length; i++) {
    byteArr[i] = (byte) ((int) ints.get(i));
}
String out = new String(byteArr);
System.out.println(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с 9 версии Java появился метод [`String.chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--):

> Returns a stream of `int` zero-extending the `char` values from this sequence. Any char which maps to a *surrogate code point* is passed through uninterpreted.
>
> **Returns:** an IntStream of char values from this sequence

Метод возвращает `IntStream` по значениям символов `char` из строки.

```java
String str = "AsDfGhJkLoIpUyTr";

int[] chars = str.chars().toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
// [65, 115, 68, 102, 71, 104, 74, 107, 76, 111, 73, 112, 85, 121, 84, 114]

String encoded = Arrays.stream(chars)
        // число в виде строки
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        // лидирующие нули
        .map(s -> "000" + s)
        // последние 3 символа
        .map(s -> s.substring(s.length() - 3))
        // объединяем в одну строку
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

// вывод
System.out.println(encoded);
// 065115068102071104074107076111073112085121084114
```

---

В таблице [ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) всего 128 символов, в основном это цифры, латинские буквы и некоторые спецсимволы. В таблице [UTF-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) для кириллических букв используются четырехзначные коды символов, начинаются с 1024. См. [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> A `String` represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which *supplementary characters* are represented by *surrogate pairs*.

Класс `String` представляет строки в формате `UTF-16`, в котором дополнительные символы представлены *суррогатными парами*.

Метод [`String.chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--) не обрабатывает *суррогатные пары*. Этого достаточно для представления большинства символов, в т. ч. кириллических и греческих букв. Есть ещё метод [`String.codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints--), который обрабатывает также *суррогатные пары*.